# Why do primitive types have a "Class" and how is it intended to be used?

Tags: java, types

Talking about Java (7) you can get a class for a primitive type like this:

```
Class classOfInt = int.class
```

For each one you'll get a "class" named as the primitive type:

```
int.class    --> int
byte.class   --> byte
double.class --> double
...
```

However you can't create an instance of those:

```
char.class.newInstance(); // throws 'InstantiationException'
```

It seems that their classes are not mapped to corresponding wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Byte`, etc.).

So why do they have "classes", how are they used and how are they implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are used in reflection.

```
Method round = Math.class.getMethod("round", double.class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(round.getParameterTypes()));
System.out.println(round.getReturnType() == long.class);

Method exit = System.class.getMethod("exit", int.class);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exit.getParameterTypes()));
System.out.println(exit.getReturnType() == void.class);
```

prints

```
[double]
true
[int]
true
```

> how are they implemented?

They are builtin to the JVM, there is no class file to define them.

Comment: So `java.lang.Class` should more accurately be called `java.lang.Type`.

Comment: Yes, but `java.lang.reflect.Type` was added much later.  It also has the problem that it doesn't have any particularly useful methods like Class does. ;)

Comment: Yes, I know of `java.lang.reflect.Type`. It's more general and more useless ;-) But the fact that `Class` represents classes, interfaces, enum types, annotation types and primitive types has cause *some* confusion already. And at least 3 of those existed in Java 1.0 as well.

Comment: I would add array types to the list as well and `void.class` which is none of the above.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, aren't annotation types classes?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: only in the sense in which interfaces are classes (because on the byte-code level annotation types are interface types with a special flag). So "yes and no". They *are* stored in `.class` files, but so are enum types (which really *are* classes in disguise). But still: `void.class`, array types and primitive types are *not* classes (at least in so far as they are *not* stored in `.class` files).

Comment: Thanks for your answers / comments so far

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I never noticed annotations were interfaces rather than classes before.  Seems like an odd choice.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard You can extend an annotation in an interface or implement it with a class. I haven't found a use for such a  thing, but its legal.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: actually it makes sense: annotations only contain declaration and no actual code, just like interfaces. And annotations are "implemented" dynamically by the JVM at runtime (probably through a mechanism similar to proxies).

Comment: are those builtins (*"no class file"*) and annotations (*"dynamically impl.-ed"*) *"in the JVM"* **JVM-dependent**? (eg. may Sun's/Oracle's JVM differ from OpenJDK in these respects?)

Comment: [getMethod docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) here (java 1.5)

Comment: The specification of the primitive classes comes from the J.L.S and is builtin to the JVM.  There is no `class` file for these classes.